# Как в Wordpress можно убрать esc_attr из полей форм в админке?

Tags: wordpress, hook, amp

Столкнулся с проблемой в Wordpress, в которой при редактировании названия поста в админке текст проходит через `esc_attr`. В результате если пост называется, например,

> `Mega Length & Volume Curl`

То в админке при редактировании название будет выглядеть так:

> `Mega Length  &amp; Volume Curl`

То есть будут пройдены через `esc_attr` (скорее всего).

Как это пофиксить?

[image: How to fix this?]

Comment: Только что проверил - нет такого https://i.imgur.com/OWHTtJa.jpg ищи пробелму в плагинах/теме

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Проблема в теме. Спасибо, тогда вопрос не актуален.